# Проверка значения переменной

Tags: javascript

Как можно проверить, имеет ли переменная ТОЛЬКО цифры (JS)

Comment: `v.match(/^\d+$/)`

Answer (score 0):

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449623/4244707):

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: Возможно, что вопрос составлен не корректно, но данная вами функция вернет `true`, если передать в неё такую строку: `'  123  '`. Это естественно для функции, но не сочетается с вопросом.